# How to make a NodeJS TLS server accessible behind a router with CGNAT

Tags: c++, node.js, networking, server

I'm trying to run a NodeJS TLS server on my console which can be accessed externally by a C++ client, but my server is running on a router that's behind CGNAT. This problem is very frustrating since I cannot connect to the server from another computer or whatever, and can only connect locally. This is my NodeJS server (just a basic server running on port 9000):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const tls = require('tls');

const options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\Certificates\\server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\Certificates\\server-cert.pem'),
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (cleartextStream) => {
  console.log('Client connected');

  cleartextStream.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Received:', data.toString());
    cleartextStream.write('Server says: Hello from Node.js TLS Server!\n');
  });

  cleartextStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log('Node.js TLS server is running on port 9000');
});
```

I made a C++ client that can connect to this server and send and receive data using OpenSSL and winsock.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "WSAStartup failed." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(9000); // port
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "my_ip", &serverAddr.sin_addr); // ip

    if (connect(clientSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to connect to server." << std::endl;
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_CTX* sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
    if (!sslContext) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize SSL context." << std::endl;
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(sslContext);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, static_cast<int>(clientSocket));

    if (SSL_connect(ssl) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "SSL connection failed." << std::endl;
        SSL_free(ssl);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    std::string message = "Hello from C++ Client!\n";
    SSL_write(ssl, message.c_str(), message.size());

    char buffer[1024];
    int bytesRead = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
        std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    // Clean up
    SSL_free(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(sslContext);
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

I just have this problem that I've been trying to find the solution to for the past week and I can't find anything... If anyone can help me I would very much appreciate it. Thanks

I've tried making tunnels like page-kite and localtunnel, but they just didn't work with a TLS server.

Comment: Can you not modify your router to pass port 9000 through to your local server?

Comment: my router doesn't have a port forwarding section, but it has a virtual server section. I put all the info like the WAN port and LAN port and the LAN IP Address as the ip address my server is running on. Still no luck when i try to access from my public ip address, maybe its cuz of the cgnat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a CGNAT, it is not clear how you can use the C++ code to connect. However, if your server is really not accessible from outside the network you can try one of the two options:

1. Create a TLS tunnel using [Pinggy](https://pinggy.io):

   ```
   ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:9000  -o ServerAliveInterval=30 tls@a.pinggy.io
   ```

   This will give you a public url which will route all traffic to the TLS server on your port 9000.
2. Just create a TCP tunnel  using [Pinggy](https://pinggy.io):

   ```
   ssh -p 443 -R0:localhost:9000  -o ServerAliveInterval=30 tcp@a.pinggy.io
   ```

   This will give you a URL and a port where you can connect.

But this free tier of Pinggy tunnels only last for 60 minutes. You can register and run them in a loop. (You can spot the active URL form the dashboard). Or just subscribe to the Pro plan.

There are other alternatives to this also, such as Ngrok.